# how can I extract key value pairs from nested JSON with for loops

Tags: python, json, dictionary, nested

I have nested json in multilevel lists of dicts

Try to extract key value pairs. I can make separate listst of keys 'code_details' and of values 'url_details' with for loops. But I want to store the result as key:value pairs.

```
code_details = []
url_details = []

for item in all_content:
    code_details.append(item ['code'])
    media_details = item ['media']
    for i in media_details:
        resources_details = i['resources']
        for j in resources_details:
            url_details.append(j ['url'])
```

How can I adjust for loops to store key:value pair in a dict {'code':'url'}

json examples

```
all_content[{"code": "0100410ZWA",
      
        },
{"media": [
        {
          "containsExplicitContent": true,
          "imageType": "Packshot",
          "resources": [
            {
              "expirationDate": "2021-05-20T11:07:00Z",
              "format": "ORIGINAL",
              "url": "https://media.lingeriestyling.com/marie_jo_l'aventure-lingerie-padded_bra-tom-0120826-pink-0_L_35590.jpg"
            }
          ]}]
```

code_details example:

```
['0502570SRE',
```

'0102649ALF',
'0602640ALF',
'0502572SRE',
'0102646ALF',
'0102570SRE',
'0502571SRE',
'0602570SRE',
'0502640ALF',
'0102640ALF',
'0102574SRE',
'0502642ALF',
'0102576SRE',
'0502641ALF',
'0663321AME',
'0163244AUT',
'0563240AUT',
'0663320AME',

```
url_details example:
['https://media.lingeriestyling.com/eservices/marie_jo-lingerie-briefs-danae-0502570-red-0_3558237.jpg',
```

'https://media.lingeriestyling.com/eservices/marie_jo-lingerie-briefs-danae-0502570-red-0_3560011.jpg',
'https://media.lingeriestyling.com/eservices/marie_jo-lingerie-briefs-danae-0502570-red-2_3560012.jpg',
'https://media.lingeriestyling.com/eservices/marie_jo-lingerie-briefs-danae-0502570-red-3_3560013.jpg',
'https://media.lingeriestyling.com/eservices/marie_jo-lingerie-briefs-danae-0502570-red-0_3558965.jpg',
'https://media.lingeriestyling.com/eservices/marie_jo-lingerie-briefs-danae-0502570-red-2_3558970.jpg',
'https://media.lingeriestyling.com/eservices/marie_jo-lingerie-briefs-danae-0502570-red-3_3558976.jpg',
'https://media.lingeriestyling.com/eservices/marie_jo-lingerie-balcony_bra-raia-0102649-multicolour-0_3558308.jpg',

Comment: provide some examples please!

Answer (score 0):

You can create a dict and update it in each iteration. Notice that dict values will be a lists

```
code_details = {}

for item in all_content:
    media_details = item ['media']
    # we need to clean it every iteration
    url_details = []
    for i in media_details:
        resources_details = i['resources']
        for j in resources_details:
            url_details.append(j ['url'])
    # here our magic is
    code = item ['code'])
    code_details[code] = url_details
```

Comment: pd.DataFrame.from_dict(code_details) gives: ValueError: All arrays must be of the same length

Comment: Error says everything - url_details have different lenght.

Comment: I needed url values in a commaseparated string and not in a list. Changed last interation into for j in resources_details:
            url_details = j['url']. That does the trick

Comment: in your example you use it as list ;)
`code_details[code] = ",".join(url_details)`

Comment: if I use your last snippet I get for each code a commaseparated string of url's. The string as a whole is placed between quotation marks. What I need is for each code a string of commaseparated url's with each url between quotation marks.

Comment: What for? There are no quotation marks at all. If you want to directly add quotation marks, do so `url_details.append(f"\"{j['url']}\"")`

Comment: You're right. There's no need.

Comment: So, does this answer works for you? Or is there something unclear?